# Android horizontal bar chart make text overlap the image

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have this horizontal bar chart in my android app, i am using mp android chart library. The problem is i need to make the text overlap the bars not behind
this is  my current bar chart
[image]

and this is how i created my chart

```
  BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "");


        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < poll.getQuestions().get(0).getAnswers().size(); i++)
            array.add(poll.getQuestions().get(0).getAnswers().get(i).getAnswer());

        BarData data = new BarData(array, dataset);
        dataset.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PollDetailActivity.this, R.color.green)); //


        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
        mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);


        //   pieChart.getAx().setDrawLabels(false);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        //   pieChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        mChart.animateY(5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HorizontalBarChart barChart= (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

```
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
    dataset.setBarSpacePercent(35f);
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");


    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    data.setValueTextSize(20f);
    data.setDrawValues(true);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.animateY(5000);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

please add:

```
 mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
```

it will show value inside bar.